# SSRS Bearer Token for Web Api Datasource

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, reporting-services

I'm trying to create some SSRS reports that will get data from our web api.

I understand how you can set up a datasource from a particular endpoint of a web service, however connection to our api requires header values being added to the request such as the bearer token for authentication and some other values that we use along with the content type that I need back from the api.

I don't know how or if you can make changes to the request header to allow successful connection to use this as a datasource. I've come up empty from extensive googling!

Does anyone know how to do this or any articles that describe how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that solution for you is to implement your own data-processing extension, which will be able to connect to your web service endpoint and provide required headers.
See more info on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154655.aspx).